# WinForms databinding with a view model - slow to display view model changes

Tags: winforms, data-binding, mvvm, viewmodel, bindingsource

I have the following configuration...

Single form with approximately 50-60 controls (it's a lot, I know) and a single view model which is responsible for storing the state of the form. The view model properties are bound to the editable controls on the form via a BindingSource.

My problem is this... I want to be able to clear the form with a button. To clear the form, I have tried the following:

- Assigning the DataSource of the BindingSource to null and reassigning a new view model. This ends up lagging terribly.
- Setting all of the properties to null/empty in the view model and then firing the OnPropertyChanged event (my view model base class is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged). This too lags terribly, and it would, given that I'm clearing 60 fields and then firing an OnPropertyChanged event for each one.

So, is there a way I can modify the application so that it is able to clear the view model and reflect the changes on the form in timely fashion? My form requires all 50-60 controls to be on the same form, but the controls could be divided up into four logical groups. Would it be beneficial for me to break up the view model into four presenters/view models that could handle the logical groups independently? Would this impact performance and the time it takes to reflect the changes in the form?

Thanks!

Comment: @SLaks Unfortunately WPF is not an option. The application must be WinForms based.

Comment: Can you embed a WPF control in the WinForms?

Comment: @SLacks I'm sure I could, but I would like to keep this strictly WinForms if possible. I suppose I'll see if anyone else chimes in with any sort of solution before exploring embedded WPF controls as an option.